# how to crop the background image in css

Tags: css

Actually i am i have one transparent background **stripe** image which i will repeat in the background of my **div** but i want to crop that image in triangular type so how i can do that with **CSS**

**Actually image which i have** [image]

**And expected result which i am trying to achieve like mentioned below image transparent stripe image so how i can crop this image in css** [image]

Comment: This is a little unclear for me, could you provide the code you have tried with, that might help me.

Comment: LIke this ...................http://tinkerbin.com/GsG4hJOp

Comment: can you use the stripe background multipal times in multipal divs  to create the effect?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if you can manage to use the strip background multipals times(managing the strips not to mismatch) then this is what you need to do **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ubeqop/3/)**

```
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2"></div>
  <div id="d3"></div>
  <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#d1 {background:#f00;
height: 80px;
width: 400px; position:relative}

#d4{background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);height:80px; width:340px; left:60px; position:absolute;}

#d2{position:absolute;font-size:0px;left:20px;width: 0px; border-top: 40px solid red;
border-right: 40px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}

#d3{position:absolute;font-size:0px;left:20px;top:40px;width: 0px;
border-top: 40px solid red;
border-right: 40px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);}
```

EDIT: updated the link

Answer (score 0):

This is my result:

[image: just a demo]

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/GAkZS/)

Note: i did it with a `rgba` background, but i'm pretty sure you can do it with [`border-image`](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) too.

HTML:

```
<div id="bgWrapper">
<div id="retina"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#bgWrapper {
    background:url(main-background-image.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    height:6em;
    position:relative;
}
#retina {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:8em; right:0; bottom:0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
#retina:before {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:-6em; bottom:0;
    width:3em;
    border-left:3em solid transparent;
    border-top:3em solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4); /* same as #retina background */
    border-bottom:3em solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4); /* same as #retina background */
}
```

​